# Can RS485 be considered a multi-master bus?

Tags: can, rs485, multi-master

There are some electrical specifications specifically designed for multi-master protocols such as CAN, I2C, 1-Wire, etc. which are classified under [CSMA/CD networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSMA/CD).

However, RS485 has a push pull output (with a current limit guard) so when two masters are started sending data at the same time, both frames will  be corrupted and the re-transmission should be handled by the protocol stack. RS485 can be classified under [CSMA/CA networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSMA/CA).

## Question

Is only protocols implemented on top of CSMA/CD networks considered as "multi master protocols" or can any protocol on CSMA/CA network that somehow implements handshake (ACK) and re-transmission features be considered as a "multi master protocol"?

Specifically, is implementing a multi-master protocol on top of RS-485 possible, or is it considered only a workaround because of the inability of collision detection nature of the bus?

Comment: The bus arbitration you describe for CAN is based on message identifiers, not by some "master priority" - CAN doesn't have masters or node id on the data link layer. Neither does RS-485. What you describe is simply CSMA/CA versus CSMA/CD. Master and slave are concepts of higher layers in the OSI model. Typically RS-485 based protocols use handshaking over hardware or software to prevent collisions. But also star topologies with a master in the middle, where all traffic has to pass the master.

Comment: Yes, the bus arbitration for CAN is based on message identifiers, which can be interpreted as node ID, thus the priority of the node. One physical node can send different messages with different identifiers, thus can be considered as "one physical device with multiple roles". I intentionally skipped this detail. You are also correct for the other claims. However, we are restricting our case with [bus network topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_network).

Comment: RS485 is just an electrical specification. To transmit any data over RS485 you have to define your own protocol. Although it is not possible (or at least not easy) to implement collision detection you can have a multi-master protocol by other means, such as token passing. This is perfectly legal and normal.

Comment: @ceremcem "CAN is based on message identifiers, which can be interpreted as node ID"  No. Node id is a higher layer concept. Application layer standards like CANopen use node id as an offset to some CAN identifiers, but nothing in the CAN physical/data link layers mentions this. You keep mixing up all layers.

Comment: @Lundin "No. Node id is a higher layer concept" Depends on how you interpret things. Think that every physical node is restricted to be able to send only one type of messages. The message ID becomes node ID and node ID becomes message ID. Notice that my short explanation in the question is not for only CAN, but for also I2C, 1Wire etc. This is a meta concept. You have to send node specific (thus message specific) ID at the beginning of telegram in order to prioritize the communication. My question boils down to the point: "is a CSMA/CA network eligible for implementing multi-master protocols?"

Comment: "Think that every physical node is restricted to be able to send only one type of messages." No such restrictions exist except on the application layer, and this is something completely separated from how the physical layers work. It is for example perfectly possible to design a CAN network with no node id, where every node sends the very same message, time multiplexed. Similarly, node id could be placed as part of the payload. Study how node id actually works in CANopen and for example RS-485 based Profibus. Very different concepts, yet this is not because of the underlaying hardware.

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @SteveG Token passing brings almost no benefits over polling especially for event driven IO applications (lightweight data where the destination is always the same node). Line is busy all the time while no useful payload is being transmitted and every node has to wait its turn to talk to.

Comment: @ceremcem you asked if a multi-master protocol was possible, not if its superior in your application.

Comment: RS 485 driver is not a multi-master driver.

Comment: Technically CAN should be called CSMA/CR (collision resolution), because unlike in CD, the highest priority of the colliding messages gets through unscathed. In CD, all are lost.

Answer (score 3):

RS485 is purely a physical layer specification. You need your own protocol for anything you run over it eg home made, or something like [MODBUS](https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/a-quick-tutorial-on-rs485-and-modbus). Normally I would have just one master that requests information from connected devices. For anything multimaster or more complex the use a different bus eg CAN or Ethernet

Comment: Please see my update in the question.